# Reading a struct

Tags: c, fread

I'm trying to read the header of a packet and then read the payload. But somehow reading payload just doesn't work for me. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
FILE *inputfile

struct packet {
    unsigned short blocksize;
    unsigned char *payload;
};  

while(!feof(inputfile)) { 
    struct packet p;
    p.payload = malloc(p.blocksize);

    fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, infp); //reads the header
    fread(p.payload, sizeof(char), p.blocksize, inputfile); //reads the payload
}
```

Comment: is that compilable code?? (it's missing some brackets)

Comment: the brackets are in my code, left it out when I was copy/pasting into this. and no it's not my full code.

Comment: Please paste compilable code that the community can understand; no body knows how your code is laid out but you and the omission of even 1 bracket could mean a memory leak, a seg fault or any other numerous errors.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, infp); //reads the header
```

should be something

```
fread(&p.blocksize, sizeof(short), 1, infp); //reads the header size
```

---

then malloc that much

```
p.payload = malloc(p.blocksize);
```

then read its payload

```
fread(p.payload, sizeof(char), p.blocksize, inputfile); //reads the payload
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things:

- You are missing the closing bracket for the `struct` statement.
- You `malloc()` before knowing what the block size is. You need to read the block size from the file before calling `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!feof(inputfile)) { 
    struct packet p;

    fread(&p.blocksize, sizeof(short), 1, infp); //Now you got the blocksize

    p.payload = malloc(p.blocksize);  // Allocate memory based on blocksize
    if( p.payload == NULL )  return -1 ; // Error...could not allocate mem

    fread(p.payload, sizeof(char), p.blocksize, inputfile); //reads the payload
}
```

After everything, make sure that you have done `free(p.payload) ;`